# Simulate mouse move on safari with protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, safaridriver

I have a function to simulate mouse move with protractor 5.0.0, safari webdriver2.48.

```
browser.actions()
  .mouseMove(this.getCanvas().getWebElement(), points[0])
  .mouseDown()
  .mouseMove(this.getCanvas().getWebElement(), points[1])
  .mouseUp()
  .perform();
```

I cannot mouse move on element of Safari.
How I can do it?

Comment: What if you would mouse move to `this.getCanvas()` (omitting the `getWebElement`part)?

Comment: It mean "element(by.id('canvas')). Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried to do it without the  `getWebElementpart` part?

Comment: Yes, but it show error and it is mandatory to get element of protractor